# Crud in jsp/Servlet with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsp, crud

I got 500 Error when I run my code the error exactly like this :

type: Exception report

message:

description: The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

I cannot solve it does anyone can help me?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VSrnGnCSJidUaNZswvTlmzkKAIiJ2D5T/view?usp=sharing

I attach zip of my code. Please check this

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The relevant code, and the complete exception stack trace allowing to know what the problem is, must be posted in the question itself, as properly formatted text. We won't install postgresql, try to build and run your code, and go through every possible thing you can do with your application to guess when the problem happens and what it is.

Comment: I do not know exactly what is the problem so I should add my whole project

Comment: No, you shouldn't. You should post the stack trace, and the relevant code, as text, in the question.

Comment: thanks for helping but still I don't know the exact problem but again thanks for your helping

Comment: Fortunately, you don't need to know the exact problem to post the stack trace of the exception and the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Index.html**

**
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Insert Data</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Give Servlet reference to the form as an instances
    GET and POST services can be according to the problem statement-->
    <form action="./InsertData" method="post">
        <p>ID:</p>
        <!-- Create an element with mandatory name attribute,
        so that data can be transfer to the servlet using getParameter() -->
        <input type="text" name="st_id"/>
        <br/>
        <p>Name:</p>
        <!-- Create an element with mandatory name attribute,
        so that data can be transfer to the servlet using getParameter() -->
        <input type="text" name="st_name"/>
        <br/>
        <p>Surname:</p>
        <input type="text" name="st_last"/>
        <br/>
        <p>Major:</p>
        <!-- Create an element with mandatory name attribute,
        so that data can be transfer to the servlet using getParameter() -->
        <input type="text" name="st_major"/>
        <br/>
        <p>Year:</p>
        <!-- Create an element with mandatory name attribute,
        so that data can be transfer to the servlet using getParameter() -->
        <input type="text" name="grad_year"/>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>`enter code here`**
```